# What is the most pythonic way to have inverse enumerate of a list?

Tags: python, reverse, enumerate

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
>>> l = list('abcdef')
>>> for i in range(len(l)-1, -1, -1):
...   item = l[i]
...   print(i, item)
...
5 f
4 e
3 d
2 c
1 b
0 a
```

I tried using the following:

```
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> for i,ch in reversed(enumerate(l)):
...   print(i,ch)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not reversible
```

but apparently 'enumerate' object is not reversible. I can trick it with:

```
>>> for i,ch in reversed(list(enumerate(l))):
...   print(i,ch)
...
5 f
4 e
3 d
2 c
1 b
0 a
```

but that doesn't feel right - it's a bit cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe some `inverse_enumerate` hidden is a lib like collections or itertools?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is probably the best option here.

Comment: You can enumerate from 1, and negate the index, because -1 == 5, -2 == 4, and so on, with python indexing. If not, you can still use `len(string) - i` and get the value you're looking for.

Comment: `list(enumerate(s))[::-1]`

Comment: This is what I did: `reversed(list(enumerate(array)))` - You have to convert the generator to a list before reversing it.

Comment: `sorted( enumerate( l, reverse=True ) )`

Answer (score 5):

That might not be the most pythonic approach, but you could reuse the code provided by the [documentation on `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to re-implement your own reversed `enumerate`.

The doc provides the following code:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

Here is a proposal for a `renumerate` function, that yields elements of a sequence in the reversed order:

```
def renumerate(sequence, start=None):
    n = start
    if start is None:
        n = len(sequence) - 1
    for elem in sequence[::-1]:
        yield n, elem
        n -= 1
```

Unfortunately, this will not work with generators, since it requires knowing the length of the sequence.

Comment: Whats wrong with `sorted( enumerate(), reverse=True )`?

Comment: @Suuuehgi that sorts, which is not what is wanted here.

Comment: @AdamBarnes this sorts based on the first item of the tuples yielded by `enumerate` so it's fine - however the sorting might be inefficient

Comment: My mistake, I misunderstood completely.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the definition of *pythonic* but you can do the following (in increasing order of complexity).

**TLDR**: Take method 3.

For comparison, I also list the maximum memory footprints (**M**) using [Gnu time](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/) as well as the computation times (**T**) using the jupyters built-in function `%timeit -n 4 -r 4`.

The reference size

```bash
/usr/bin/time -v python3 -c 'list( int(1e6) * "abcdef" )'
```

results in 61.4 MB.

---

##### Method 1

As suggested earlier:

```py
reversed( list( enumerate(l) ) )
```

`enumerate` returns a generator, and generators are not invertible.

So `list` internally creates a new list by iterating over the entire generator (until a `StopIteration` exception is thrown) and `reversed` creates a generator along that list in reverse order.

This is simple and probably "pythonic", but creates significant memory overhead (during copying and due to the copying itself).

| **M** | **T (ms per loop [mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each])** |
| --- | --- |
| 673.6 MB | 1.03 s ± 61.3 ms |

---

##### Method 2

As written in my comment, you can also use

```
sorted( enumerate(), reverse=True )
```

which is slighly more clear as the above and does pretty much the same.
`sorted` also internally create a copy with the associated memory-overhead but additionally a sorting operation.
As sorting a sorted list is rather fast, the run-time overhead is tiny.

So you are trading readability for runtime here.

| **M** | **T (ms per loop [mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each])** |
| --- | --- |
| 673.6 MB | 1.28 s ± 30.2 ms |

---

##### Method 3

For what you ask, as far as I know, there is no built-in generator or way to chain generators. But you can easily write one yourself, and that is what I recommend:

```
def enumerate_reversed(l):
    return zip(range(len(l)-1, -1, -1), reversed(l))
```

Or as one-liner:

```py
enumerate_reversed = lambda l: zip(range(len(l)-1, -1, -1), reversed(l))
```

`reversed`, `range` and `zip` all return generators.
This way you get an inverted `enumerate` without creating any intermediate copies.

| M | T (ms per loop [mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each]) | T (lambda) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 61.8 MB | 1.04 s ± 26.7 ms | 1.04 s ± 30.6 ms per loop |

---

Appendix:

Commands used:

| Method | Command |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" python3 -c 'reversed(list(enumerate(list(int(1e6)*"abcdef"))))'` |
| 2 | `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" python3 -c 'sorted(enumerate(list(int(1e6)*"abcdef")),reverse=True)'` |
| 3 | `/usr/bin/time -f "%M" python3 -c 'f = lambda l: zip(range(len(l)-1, -1, -1), reversed(l)); f(list(int(1e6)*"abcdef"))'` |

Comment: to long, didnt read: Its used to guide lazy readers to the core information

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry for the created confusion. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Method 3 is what I would recommend. Note the that generator expression isn't necessary; `lambda l: zip(range(...), reversed(l))` is equivalent.