# How can I print python generator object in reversed order?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def generatorFun(n):
    number = 0
    while number < n:
        yield number
        number += 1
myGenerator = generatorFun(10)
print(next(myGenerator))
print(next(myGenerator))
print(next(myGenerator))
```

How can I print the result in reversed order?
10
9
8
7
....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should give this a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561214/python-reverse-generator

Comment: You have to store all the values in a container, like a list, and then iterate over that in reverse

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without storing the values in a list and reversing the list. Reversing a generator directly isn't possible because generators can be infinite:

```
def infinite():
    while True:
        yield 1
```

Comment: Isn't it possible with tuples, too?

Comment: @KellyBundy, yeah, any storage will work: lists, tuples, dictionaries, `array.array`s, `collections.deque`s - anything that stores the values of the generator in memory